# JavaScript - have multiple checkboxes but only able to select one while updating a dollar value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what I'm having trouble doing.

I want to be able to display 4 checkboxes next to each other while only being able to select one at a time. While one is checked, I want that value to be added to a total sum that comes from another section of checkboxes.

I have been fighting with this all night (6 hours) and have gone forward and backwards in my attempts.

**HTML**

```
    Checkboxes test 1:
<input type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" value="5" />


<section id="extra-features">
    <label class="header">How often?</label><br><br>
                        <div class="span3">
                        <label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
                            <input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox"> Daily
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input value="50"  type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox"> 3 times a week
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input value="50"  type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox"> Once a week
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input value="50"  type="checkbox" class="sum checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox"> Custom
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </section>

<div class="card-charge-info">
                    Total per mo. $<span id="payment-total">0</span>
                </div>
```

In the above HTML code that I have mashed together, I have a section of checkboxes that uses (posted after this block) a JS script in order to uncheck a box if another one is checked. Those boxes also have values that are added to a 'sum' BUT the issue that occurs is this:
When clicking on a box that is already checked, the value is subtracted from the overall sum. If I click on another box, and the first box is unchecked by the JS script, the value is not subtracted from the overall sum but the box itself is unchecked.

The code under the 'checkbox test' is another block of checkboxes that I have not been able to apply the unchecking idea too. The same issue with sum not being subtracted would surely be prevalent anyway.

**JS**

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});


var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
        total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');

 for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onchange = function() {
            var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
        }
    }
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MGilbert/qbcu9cjt/10/)

Comment: Without your code, HTML and JavaScript, what help did you think we might be able to provide? I have no issues with the question except that we can't help without the code.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, as I am unable to post my code at this moment, i felt it could still be useful if someone had a general idea that this is possible. (I'm sure it is, but haven't been able to find anything). Let me see if my laptop is charged and then I can post a jsfiddle

Comment: Bear in mind that a JS Fiddle is a *bonus*, the relevant "*[mcve]*" code must also be present in the question to allow us to reproduce your problem. Also, it might be worth taking a look at the "*[ask]*" page to see what we expect of a good question (definition of the problem, the code of the problem, description of what does/doesn't work, the expectations you have and any error messages that may have occurred).

Comment: Thank you for the insight, David. I have just updated my post with what I feel is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is a radio button, which will allow only one of a group to be selected. Once you have done this, assign a value to the radiobutton which will be returned when you submit the form. Then use this value however you wish.

Comment: Is there a way to have the sum update without submitting?

Comment: You can use angular js, but I think maybe that is outside the scope of the question. Look up ng-model.

Comment: If you assign ng-model inside of the input radiobutton it should work. Here is an example:.  <input type="radio" ng-model="string" value="string"> please read the radiobutton example on that page, I think it has what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for that idea, Jordan. I checked it out for a moment and am curious if you would know offhand... Would I be able to take multiple groups of those and have a tallied sum?

Comment: You can Definitely do that, just make sure that you assign a value to each textbox and you should be good to go.

Comment: Interesting, going to mess with it for a little in jsfiddle :)